# Sudoku and absolute value equation

Tags: absolute-value

I know there is many mathematical way to reformulate the Sudoku problem. I'm wondering if there is a way to reformulate this problem as an absolute value equation :

\begin{equation}
Ax + B|x|=b
\end{equation}
where x  and b $\in \mathbb{R}^n$, A and B $\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the absolute value?
I would expect solution space to be positive integers 1-9 anyway. I'd also expect integer coefficients in A and B.

Comment: I'm looking for application of this kind of equation. Also x depend on reformulation, so I guess it's not necesseraly positive integer 1-9.